# How to remove extra white space in html table cells?

Tags: html, css

[image]

How do I remove the extra line space between blocks of text? (*i.e.* January 29th and 31st cells in image). 
And is there a way to remove padding from `td` so words could fill the cell width a little more? (*i.e.* "Observational" in week 2 topic cell to bottom left of image).

Here is some of the code:

```css
th {
  width=16.66%;
  height: 30;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tues</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thurs</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:1px;margin:0;"></td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">27</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">28</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">29</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">30</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">31</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Week 2: Chapters 2-3</b><br>(Observational Studies)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <p style="color:red;font-size:100%;">HW Assignment 1 Due</p><br>
        <p style="color:blue;font-size:100%;">Chapter 2 Part 1 Prelecture Due</p>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <p style="color:red;font-size:100%;">HW Assignment 2 Due</p><br>
        <p style="color:blue;font-size:100%;">Chapter 2 Part 2 Prelecture Due</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: int the p element and on the td also put `padding:0px !important; margin:0px !important;`

Comment: If this is not for an HTML email, you should be replacing all that inline style with CSS Classes

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<br>` between your 2 `p` tags on each of those that is adding extra space. Just remove that.

If you want even less space you could also lower/remove the margin on your `p` tags

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Not all of your CSS seems to be in your question here so other styles might be interfering also, but you can likely change the margin of the `p` tag to whatever you'd like.

Comment: How would I keep the homework and prelecture objects separate without <br>?

Comment: @LegendOfKass `p+p {margin-top:1em;/* or whatever value you want */}` is an option to remove the br in between p. you can also increase line-height if that's to increase the gap in between every lines

Answer (score 1):

To remove border gap between blocks in table, you need to add `border-collapse: collapse` in your table style.

`<table border-collapse="collapse" border="1">`

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<br>` between your 2 `p` tags, remove `margin: 0` on your `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

to add from an earlier comment.

there's a few elements with default margins and padding that you can reset ,  you can reset these at once for all of them with : `* {margin:0;padding:0;}` if it bothers you to mind each element.

To set a box away from another , you can also reset margin , or padding only to the few that matters . `p+p` is an option to add a margin top only from the second `p` appearing so you can remove the `<br>` to be used inside a piece of text or in between inline boxes.

You can also increase `line-height` if that's what you want at every line of text , usually `line-height:1.6em` is an average value for reading confort you can use.

CSS requires `:` in between rules and values, not `=` *(there was a typo for `th`  `width` )*.

example with `line-height` and the sibbling selector  `+` to remove the `br` tags , also a `display` reset on your `b` tag.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p+p {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

b {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

th {
  width: 16.66%;
  height: 30px; /* value was missing */
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65%;
  padding-top:1em; 
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Week</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tues</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thurs</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="line-height:1px;margin:0;"></td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">27</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">28</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">29</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">30</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p style="font-size:95%;line-height:1px;margin:0;text-align:center;">31</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Week 2: Chapters 2-3</b>(Observational Studies)</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <p style="color:red;font-size:100%;">HW Assignment 1 Due</p>
        <p style="color:blue;font-size:100%;">Chapter 2 Part 1 Prelecture Due</p>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <p style="color:red;font-size:100%;">HW Assignment 2 Due</p>
        <p style="color:blue;font-size:100%;">Chapter 2 Part 2 Prelecture Due</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

if you want some reading :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height
>
> The `line-height` CSS property sets the height of a line box. It's commonly used to set the distance between lines of text. On block-level elements, it specifies the minimum `height` of line boxes within the element. On non-replaced inline elements, it specifies the `height` that is used to calculate line box height.

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
>
> The display CSS property sets whether an element is treated as a block or inline element and the layout used for its children, such as flow layout, grid or flex.

---

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator
>
> The adjacent sibling combinator (`+`) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

also usefull to know : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

---

I hope this helps you find more options you can have via CSS to set for your layouts.